# how to use on-change with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bind 2 properties to a object. The DocumentTypeId, DocumentTypeName. I am using ng-repeat in a select box, i could not get it to work with ng-options. This hack is causing me problems. I have ngstorage setup in my project, I can get the DocumentTypeName from the $rootScope, problem is I cant execute the function correctly.The parameter in the ng-change function is undefined. I would prefer to get rid of the hack and use ng-options, if not then I just need this to work. open to suggestions, thanks

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qv3fqVgH2JzEcGRoKY3T?p=preview)

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.documentTypeId" ng-change="selectDocumentType(docType)">
    <option ng-repeat="docType in docTypes" title="{{docType.DocumentTypeName}}" ng-selected="{{docType.DocumentTypeId == model.DocumentTypeId}}" value="{{docType.DocumentTypeId}}">
        {{docType.DocumentTypeName}}
    </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Sounds like the XY problem.. why not make it work with `ng-options` ?

Comment: I could not get it to work. If you could take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it work with `ng-options`, like you said, it's best if you used that instead of a hack.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="model.documentTypeId" ng-change="test()"
         ng-options="docType.DocumentTypeId as docType.DocumentTypeName for docType in docTypes" title="{{docType.DocumentTypeName}}" ng-selected="{{docType.DocumentTypeId == model.DocumentTypeId}}" value="{{docType.DocumentTypeId}}">
            {{docType.DocumentTypeName}}
</select>
```

And the `ng-change` is just a test function in the controller so you see it works:

```
$scope.test = function (docType) {
     console.log($scope.model.documentTypeId);
};
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uhVdYbcFRNMJofaXpkQV?p=preview)

Comment: outstanding! any chance you can get the function working http://plnkr.co/edit/gk0CH9otck8J7fYdLsbY?p=preview     thanks

Comment: @texas697 I made a couple of changes. Chagned the `ng-model` from `model.documentTypeId` to just `documentTypeId`, and removed the parameter from `selectDocumentType()` since you don't need it.

Comment: really appreciate your help!!